# How to detect neighbors patches coordinator (position)?

Tags: netlogo

How to detect coordinators (positions) of neighbors patches which surrounding the patch that a turtle is on? Something like:

```
patches with [(pcolor = red) and (any? turtles-on neighbors)]
```

or

```
[patch-here] of neighbors with [(pcolor = red)]
```

I would want to move the turtle to a neighbor patch with red color. So I will need to find that neighbor patch with red color first. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

one-of may do what you want here (http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of).  Something like this:

```
to move-turtle
    let destination one-of neighbors with [ pcolor = red ]
    if (destination != NOBODY) [
        move-to destination
    ]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit difficult to figure out what you want, but I think you are suggesting to work with coordinates rather than with patches.  If so, don't do that unless there is a good reason.  In this case you can just

```
to move ;; turtle proc
  let %candidates neighbors with [pcolor = red]
  if (any? %candidates) [
    move-to one-of %candidates
  ]
end
```